# Handling exceptions during unit testing and code coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have try-catch structure in my node.js code which looks like:

```
try {
  //do some code
}
catch(e) {
  logError(e);
}
```

I have a feeling that this approach is not very good, but the most biggest problem is the unit testing (mocha and chai) and code coverage (nyc). I can test catch section only by provoking exception just in work code, but in this case I will need come flag structure just inside the code to manage the flow like:

```
try {
  if(testingFlag)
    throw new Error('Test error');
//do some code
}
catch(e) {
  logError(e);
}
```

Only in this case I will be able to change the script direction and test this section.
Basically the questions is: is there any best practice to handle exceptions, semantic and code errors in a proper way to be able to do unit testing and code coverage without any problems?
Thanks.

Comment: What does `do some code` actually do? How could you provoke it to error *from outside* - bad inputs? Does it have collaborators you could replace with test doubles that throw errors? If you can't get it to error from outside, does it really need the error handling mechanism? I would absolutely *not* recommend having a *"I am currently being tested"* flag in your code (worst case, prison: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-41053740).

Comment: @jonrsharpe 'do some code' actually doing different stuff, I'm using this approach with try-catch almost everywhere. Let's assume this 'stuff' doesn't includes any troubles with call back functions which means that exception always being caught. By provoking error from outside I mean that I can change testingFlag from outside. So, I have testingFlag as an module.exports variable. During unit testing I do 2 sets of the same tests: one for testingFlag=false and one for testingFlag=true

Comment: Just to be clear: the testing flag is a terrible idea. Don't do it. Think about what can happen during *actual execution of the code* that would cause errors, like the examples I gave above. If the answer is "nothing", remove the redundant code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Ok, but what about the subject? How can I cover and test catch section?

Comment: I don't know how else to put it. It's going to depend on the code. If there are inputs that cause it to fail, pass those. If there are errors or outputs from collaborators that cause it to fail, use test doubles. If neither, *do you even need it?* Also, you don't need to reach 100% code coverage, it's not necessarily a useful measure of whether your code or the tests are any good.

Comment: The jonrsharpe comment about 100% code coverage not being necessary is absolutely right - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55778603/5747415 for some explanation.