# In Android projects, what's the reasonable code coverage that can be achieved by Unit Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing

In my recent Android project I am asked to set a goal for Unit Test Coverage. I want to know what's the reasonable amount of coverage achievable, 30%, 50% or 70%?

Comment: It depends on code it self. But of course best practice is to cover as much as possible

Comment: Same question as what is quality. Different answer for different client. You may consider to use Pareto principle - just cover 20% of codebase that's causing biggest impact.

Comment: to add to what @ror says - another factor is team size. you have to be practical about balancing testing and feature implementation. lots of code is boilerplate and doesn't need testing

Comment: as it hinted above, depends on the code, anyway JVM JUnit up to 60% (not exact) and instrumentation up to 25% (not exact)

Answer (score 1):

As was written in the comments, there is no single number, because it depends on the code.

- For automatically generated code the percentage can even be 0% - certainly, the code generator would have to be tested (as well as the code snippets used by the generator), plus the source file that controls the generator.  But, if that all is done, unit-testing for the generated code might not bring any additional value.
- Sometimes wrapper code is introduced to separate a component from its dependencies.  The wrappers are there to be mocked, but not to be unit-tested.
- Robustness code (like, a default case in a switch statement that already covers all cases explicitly) can not sensibly be unit-tested, because it is unreachable.
- Some code consists only of interactions and thus should be integration tested rather than unit-tested.
- Some code (it can be argued) is just too trivial to bring any value when unit-tested.

Setting coverage goals also brings some risks:

- Since it is easier to cover trivial code, you may end up with, say, 80% code coverage, where the trivial 80% of the code are covered, but the horribly difficult (and thus also likely buggy) 20% of the code are not.  And, the 80% coverage give your management a false impression of low risk.
- Even code that is covered may not be well tested.  It may not even be tested at all - only executed, without evaluation of the results.

Unfortunately, it is seldom that a quality organisation will accept such arguments.  Which on the other hand is understandable, because development often enough postpones quality activities to be able to fulfill customer deadlines.

The best approach would be to have one or more quality *engineers* (not quality managers) in the project, who are trusted by the quality organization, but on the other hand do not simply look at coverage percentages, but at the true quality of the test suites.